# Chart.js do not apply x-axis custom config

Tags: javascript, charts

**Resolved on update 26-04-2021** (see below)

I encountered troubles to define the x-axis on Charts.js version `3.1.0`.

Time is formatted as ISO standard (javascript so): `'2021-04-12T01:51:40'`
Chart configuration `options.scaled[scaledId]` defined for x-axis can only be an array (not an object as [described in the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/time-line.html)). And it appears that defining an array do not apply the custom x-axis configuration.

I tried to define the x-axis `options.scaled[x]` as an object but it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: This method is not implemented: either no adapter can be found or an incomplete integration was provided.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
```

Have someone encountering the same issue and/or having an idea about this ?

---

Sample code:

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.1.0/dist/chart.min.js'></script>

<script>
var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'RENAULT TWINGO',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: [
                    {x: '2021-04-11T01:51:40', y: 132},
                    {x: '2021-04-12T03:57:03', y: 102}
                ],
            },
            {
                label: 'CITROEN C3',
                borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                data: [
                    {x: '2021-04-11T01:51:40', y: 123},
                    {x: '2021-04-12T03:57:03', y: 143}
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    options: {
        plugins: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Prix des voitures',
        }
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            x: [{
                axis: 'x',
                type: 'timeseries',
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Temps',
                },
                ticks: {
                  source: 'data'
                },
                time: {
                    // parser: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss',
                    unit: 'day',
                    displayFormats: {
                        'day': 'DD/MM'
                    },
                },
            }],
            y: {
                axis: 'y',
                type: 'linear',
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Prix',
                },
                beginAtZero: true,
            },
        }
    }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
</script>
```

and its result:
[image]

The expected result would be the date formated as `DD/MM` (i.e. `11/04` and `12/04`).

---

**Updated on 26-04-2021**

It was missing the date format library **AND** the related adapter.

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.27.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@0.1.1"></script>
```

Thus object assignation for the `x-axis` works well.

```js
scales: {
    x: {
        axis: 'x',
        type: 'time',
        time: {
            parser: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss',
            unit: 'minute',
            displayFormats: {
                'minute': 'DD-MM HH:mm'
            },
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove the square array brackets around the X config so it will be `x: {}` instead of `X:[{}]`

EDIT:
Since chart.js v3 moment isn't shipped anymore by default and so also no date adapters. To use the timescale you will need to also include a date adapter as explained here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters

Comment: That’s what I explained in my description changing the array to object returns an error. The error has been explicitly exposed in this issue. Do you have any other ideas ? My sample code is also given to help me debugging. Thx

Comment: Adapters are the point I missed; Thanks !